# Copiar texto de uma textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-basic-6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que o botão "Copiar" copie todo o texto da textbox?

Comment: Visual Basic 6 e Visual Basic .NET são linguagens distintas, em qual delas queria sua resposta?

Comment: Visual Basic .NET, não sabia que eram distintas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi é para copiar para área de transferência, então é assim no VB:

```
Clipboard.SetText(Text1.Text)
```

onde Text1.text é seu texto

Comment: Exato! Obrigado. ^^

Answer (score -2):

Private Sub Command1_Click()
txt.SelStart = 0
txt.SelLength = Len(txt.Text)
txt.SetFocus
Clipboard.Clear
Clipboard.SetText Screen.ActiveControl.SelText
End Sub

Answer (score -3):

Esse é bem simples:

```
<button type="button"id="MY_ID" data-clipboard-text="Texto de Exemplo" class="btn btn-link">Copiar</button>
```

Comment: Tão simples que errou.